# Why am I recieving a 'list index out of range' error in this program?

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am a student relatively new to coding, using Python at GCSE level and I am struggling to see where I am going wrong with this piece of code, used to correct different students marks by an adjustment factor. Why am I getting an error when both lists have the same number of items in them?

```
wrongMark = [72,75,23,54,48]
adFactor = [1.25,1.1,1.8,1.3,0.9]
newMark = []
examTable = [["Doc","Sarah","Jar-Jar","Jake","Ben"],
             wrongMark,
             adFactor
             ]
#print(examTable)

for item in wrongMark:
    results = item*adFactor[item]
    newMark.append(results)
print(newMark)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your for loop put in a line to `print(item)`
You’ll see it is the value in wrongMark, not the index. 
You probably want

```
For index in range(len(wrongMark)):
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are using `for item in wrongMark`. In the first iteration, the loop will assign item with value 75 and the list `adFactor` doesn't have 75 items ;)

One way to solve this is just changing the loop to:

```
for item in range(len(wrongMark)):
    results = wrongMark[item]*adFactor[item]
    newMark.append(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this row:

```
   results = item*adFactor[item]
```

For the first iteration of the for loop, you are trying to access the 72th cell in the list adFactor.

That is why you get "list index out of range"

Answer (score 0):

you need to use index while iterating. You are using value which is 72 for first iteration. That is why it out of range error. Use something like :        for idx in range(len(wrongMark)):
    results = wrongMark[idx]*adFactor[idx]
    newMark.append(results)

Answer (score 0):

The error is In the code: results = item*adFactor[item]
It is easier to note the error when you imagine the first iteration of your loop to be : result = 72 * adFactor[72]
You get an  out of index  error because the list adFactor doesnt have a  72nd term.